# Getting wrong ip and port number from libpcap captured packet

Tags: c, libpcap

My Ubuntu virtual machine's IP address is 192.168.1.110. Everything else looks fine. I don't know what is wrong with the code.  Maybe I'm using a wrong package header structure? 
Below is my code and output. Again my host IP should be 192.168.1.110 and port for now is definitely wrong.

```
sudo ./sniffall 0
84.72.137.105:38055  192.168.1.105:56652
192.168.1.105:56652  174.141.213.124:28073
84.72.137.105:38055  192.168.1.105:56652
192.168.1.105:56652  174.141.213.124:28073
84.72.137.105:38055  192.168.1.105:56652


#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

void getPacket(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *pkthdr, const u_char *packet){
    struct ip *ip;
    struct tcphdr *tcp;
    ip = (struct ip*)(packet+sizeof(struct ether_header));
    tcp = (struct tcphdr*)(packet+sizeof(struct ether_header)+sizeof(struct ip));

    char* src = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src);

    printf("%s:%d ",src,tcp->source);
    char* dst = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst);
    printf(" %s:%d\n", dst, tcp->dest);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE], *device;
    device = argv[1];
    pcap_t *handle;
    handle = pcap_open_live(device, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if(!handle){
        device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
        handle = pcap_open_live(device, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
        if(!handle){
                printf("Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", device, errbuf);
        }
    }

    pcap_loop(handle, 5, getPacket, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are opening the pcap handle in promiscuous mode.  Perhaps you are seeing other traffic on the wire?

Comment: That doesn't look like the output of your program. It's not printing `:` followed by the port number. You should also use `ntohs` to convert the port number from network to host byte order.

Comment: You have a large block of code commented out. If it's not needed, it's just noise for people trying to help answer your question :-) Just a friendly note!

Comment: Thank you for advice... I updated my output, i keep the commented area basically because i am not sure which one will works.... but thanks, I will delete that.

Comment: ok, i make a few changes now, first, i changed to false for promiscuous mode, and then i add ntohs to convert the port number, but output still not make sense.

Comment: so output still looks same like one i posted before.. any ideas? thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pcap is going to show some other traffic other than your system's if you're in promiscuous mode. Why you're seeing specific packets that aren't being sent or received from your system is going to be dependent a bit on your network configuration. Some ethernet switches will occasionally leak packets destined to other systems if they're unsure where they should go, etc.

You also need to need to convert between byte orders. In most common cases now, "network byte order" is not the same as your machine's byte order. To print out the port number, you need to do something like:

```
printf("%s:%d ",src,ntohs(tcp->source));
```

Also, you may want to try `struct iphdr` instead of `struct ip`. I've seen instances before where there were multiple definitions of a struct named `ip` in headers, but `iphdr` was always right for me.

Remember that you can always run `tcpdump` in another window to see what packets are actually coming in, it's possible that you're receiving more traffic than you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

First, after calling `pcap_open_live()`, call `pcap_datalink()` on `handle` and, if it doesn't return `DLT_EN10MB`, either exit or rewrite your program so that it can handle the value it returns.  See [the tcpdump.org link-layer header types page](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) for a description of the supported values from `pcap_datalink()`.

Second, do *NOT* assume that the packet is an IPv4 packet unless you have either installed a filter of `"ip"` or have checked the packet type (e.g., the type field in an Ethernet header) to make sure the packet is an IPv4 packet.

Third, do *NOT* assume that the header of an IPv4 packet is exactly `sizeof(struct ip)` bytes long.  I assume `sizeof(struct ip)` will be 20, which is the *minimum* length of an IPv4 header, but the header may include options - check the "header length" field of the IPv4 header (which is in units of 4-byte words, so a value of 5 means "20 bytes") and use that as the length of the header (make sure it's at least 5 - if it's less than 5, the packet is not valid - and then multiply by 4 to get the length of the header).

Fourth, do *NOT* assume that the packet is a TCP packet unless you have either installed a filter of `"ip and tcp"` or just `"tcp"` (with the latter, you'll still have to check yourself to see whether it's an IPv4 packet) or have checked the "protocol" field of the IPv4 header to make sure it has a value of 6 (for TCP).